# C#_ Incorrect data when use SqlParameter and Bulk SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulk, sqlparameter

This is my code :

```
string sqllaydl = @"BULK INSERT dbo.Infosp1 FROM '@laydl' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqllaydl, con);

SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter();
para.ParameterName = "@laydl";
para.Value = txblink.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add(para);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Đã lấy DL", "Thông báo");
Hienthi();
```

The value of `@laydl` when I insert from form is

```
D:\test.txt
```

[image]

But when I used debug, the value has two backslashes `\\`.

```
D:\\test.txt
```

So, I couldn't have a link to insert data, help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your backslash is being escaped.  You have to use @"txblink.Text"

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I want the value have ONE backslash like : `D:\test.txt`